# Minimum Height of Facebook Page Tab

Tags: facebook

I am doing a facebook page tab with iframe with the height which is 530px. I have tried many methods to decrease the height of canvas, however, it can't still be lower than 800px.

Can't it be made less than 800px height ?
Anyone has such experience to make a less than 800px app?
Thanks so much !!